# Web Audio API A-Weighted Sound Level Meter

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I'm developing a A-Weighted Sound Level Meter with the Web Audio API.

I managed to do a FFT transform to the channel data, apply the A-Weight formula to the different frequencies, and do the inverse FFT to get back the resulting channel data.

My problem is that the dB level doesn't seem to be reduced enough. For example if I load a 20hz file, I would expect the resulting dB to be close to 0, but it's just a bit lower than if I don't apply the filter.

Maybe I'm just taking the wrong approach.  It's the first time I work with the Web Audio API and sound.

I prepared a repository for you with the test code, so you can just download and play with it. https://github.com/jesucarr/spl-test

Just open test.html in Chrome, load the 20hz.wav file, and open the Console. You will see that without the filter applied, the dBSPL Max is about 116, and with the filter applied is 106, but it should be close to 0.

If you open text.html you will find all the code and comments.

Is that the right approach? and if so, why the dBs are not reduced to almost 0 when loading the 20hz.wav file?

Thanks for your help

Comment: First, directly modifying the FFT may not result in a bandlimited signal so there could be audio artifacts in the result.  Also, the A-weighting link in your test specifies an equivalent filter which you could implement in WebAudio.  Don't know if that will make it more consistent or not.

Comment: You mean, is it possible create the A-Weight filter with a WebAudio BiquadFilterNode? I actually tried to add one peaking filter for each of the frequencies, but the result was extremely loud and even reducing the gain the resulting dBs not as expected.

Comment: Yes. http://www.diracdelta.co.uk/science/source/a/w/aweighting/source.html#.VsNgXJMrJE4 has the s-transform of the A-weight filter.  You'll have to convert  to a discrete-time filter, but it's 6-th order so you can use 3 biquads (or one IIRFilter) to do the filtering.  Whether that helps you or not I can't say; I didn't try this myself.

Comment: Unfortunately my maths are not so good. Any help on how to create the 3 biquads from the s-transform function (I have this function in my code)?

Comment: In that case, just use IIRFilter.  Look up bilinear transform on wikipedia to figure out how to create a discrete time filter from the continuous time s-transform.